# How to show content of all sub-directory in sub-domain for all my user on the site [htaccess]?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I would show the content of sub-directory in a sub-domain generate with htaccess.
Practically I must create a sub-domain for all user that register on my website

Example of my site web example.com:

```
/index.php
      user1/
      user2/
      user3/
```

Obviously the url are now:

```
example.com/user1/
example.com/user2
etc...
```

But I would show in the browser `user1.example.com`, `user2.example.com`, etc... without change whenever the file `.htaccess`

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Check this rewrite in top of your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/%1/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm very happy for your help.